# How can I make a pill shape? (capsule)

Tags: modeling, mesh, objects, workflow

Is there any easy way to make a basic shape that looks something like this?

[image: stockphoto crop]

Answer (score 25):

Yes, you can do it in a few steps:

*(updated as per PG math's advice)*

1. Add a sphere <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd>>*Mesh*>*Sphere*
2. Enter edit mode <kbd>Tab</kbd>
3. Set the shading to smooth
4. Grab one end, including the middle loop (use <kbd>Numpad 3</kbd> to go into side view and <kbd>Z</kbd> to be able to select vertices on the other side. Then hit <kbd>B</kbd> for box select to get everything except the middle loop.)
5. extrude it up using <kbd>E</kbd>.

[image]

**Result:**

[image]

[image]

**Bonus:**

How to add the ridge:

1. Use <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>RMB</kbd> to select the desired loop, you'll have to do this twice, once for each side.
2. Deselect the vertices at the ends of the pill
3. Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>B</kbd> to bevel the edges, make it a very very small bevel
4. in the <kbd>F6</kbd> menu, set the number of cuts to 3.
5. Select the middle cut and scale it out a bit, use <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>S</kbd>
6. Add loop cuts to the edges loops around the edge to help keep the smooth shading correct.

Comment: For the first part you can simply select the top half of the sphere and hit [E].

Comment: @PGmath Good catch!

Comment: I always forget you can extrude whole portions like that too. :)

Answer (score 6):

If you enable the **Add Mesh: Extra Objects add-on**

[image]

you'll be able to add a "**Capsule**" primitive.

[image]

Parameters such as resolution and dimensions can be tweaked in the operator panel at the bottom of the tooshelf.

Answer (score 4):

@GiantCowFilms posted a great answer, and I would recommend reading that, if you haven't already.

It should be mentioned, though, that Blender has a built-in "capsule" metaball.

Simply press shift-A, hover over "Metaball", and you'll see the "capsule" shape there.

[image]

Note that this is a different kind of shape,
and should probably be converted to a mesh using <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd>.

Comment: i dunno what the hotkey changed to in 2.81, it can be found in the spacebar menu under 'convert'