# Trying to make a curved sausage

Tags: bezier-curves

I'm new to blender and I don't know how to make a sausage with a curved shape. Can anyone help me? my problem is with the creation of the shape. I cant make the round shape of the sausage in the extremes, I dont know wich mesh to use and how to modify it so that it takes that shape. thanks

Comment: A reference would be helpful. You should find [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/34616/2217) useful.

Answer (score 6):

### Curve modifier

A common strategy is to model the object straight along an axis, for example the X axis in the following example:

[image]

And to add the object a **Curve** modifier pointing to a curve-type object that is capable of bending the object accordling to the given curve. Notice that the choice of the deformation axis is coherent with the model main direction.

[image]

The biggest advantage of using modifiers is the flexibility that they provides as you can freely modify the bending till you decide to apply it. The bending curves remain distinct objects, and can be customized/changed leaving the other as it is.

[image]

*Note: for good deformations, you'll need to provide enough polygons to the object and sufficient resolution to the curve*

Comment: yes about the curve modifier i know, but my problem is with the creation of the shape. I can`t make the round shape of the sausage in the extremes, I don`t know wich mesh to use and how to modify it so that it takes that shape

Comment: Give a look at https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/26890/how-can-i-make-a-pill-shape-capsule for an understanding of how to build a capsule object and edit your question to add all the information about what exactly you would like to achieve.