# Does Blender 2.8 have the abililty to make a cylinder with round ends

Tags: modeling

As the title says, does Blender 2.8 have ability to create a cylinder with round ends; **as part of the cylinder creation**.

I have seen the options discussed for previous versions, and will likely use the bevel option if this cannot be done.

[image: Cylinder with round ends]

Thank you,

Jim

Comment: As of now, the primitives you can add with "Shift+A - Mesh" are all there is. On the other hand, creating this capsule-like mesh takes less than a minute.

Comment: On second thought, scratch that. "Extra Meshes" is already in Blender 2.80. See [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/38578/23985) on how to install it. You can then change the "Operator Presets" to capsule and add some loop cuts. It's not really faster than creating it by hand, though...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't a builtin Capsule, which is activated by default.

But since it is a sphere with extra steps, I'll just demonstrate the steps in case they'll help someone.

1. Add a *UV Sphere*. <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>
2. Go into *edit mode*. <kbd>↹ Tab</kbd>
3. Edge Loop Select the equator. <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>[image: RMB] RMB</kbd>
4. Do the *Rip Fill*. <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>V</kbd>
5. *Border Select* the rip filled half. <kbd>B</kbd>
6. Move the half along Z. <kbd>G</kbd> <kbd>Z</kbd>
7. Add loops. <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>, <kbd>[image: MMB] MMB</kbd> scroll

[image: capsule creation]